# What is the time complexity of deciding whether a linear program is feasible?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, computational-complexity, numerical-optimization

I have a question: What is the time complexity for solving a convex feasibility problem (particularly, this question focuses on the linear feasibility problem)?
Specifically, the feasibility problem considered is expressed as follows:
\begin{align}
 \mathrm {find}
 ~&\mathcal{P} \\
 \mathrm {s.t.~} &\sum_{n=1}^{N} P_{n}^{A} g_{n} \geq \gamma\left(\sum_{n=1}^{N} P_{n}^{B} g_{n}+\sigma\right), \\
 &P_{l}^{B} g_{l} \geq v\left(\sum_{n \neq l} P_{n}^{B} g_{n}+\sigma\right), \\
 &P_{n}^{A}+P_{n}^{B} \leq P_{n}, \forall n \in\{1, \cdots, N\},
\end{align}
where $\mathcal{P} \triangleq\left\{P_{1}^{A}, \cdots, P_{N}^{A}, P_{1}^{B}, \cdots, P_{N}^{B}\right\}$ are the variables; $\left\{g_{1}, \cdots, g_{N}\right\}, \gamma, \sigma, v, l,\left\{P_{1}, \cdots, P_{N}\right\}$  are constants.

This is a feasibility problem for a linear program, and I solved it using the CVX toolbox. In my opinion, in CVX, it seems that the feasibility problem mentioned above is also solved by SDPT3 via interior-point method. Therefore, the time complexity for solving this feasibility problem is the time complexity of interior-point method, which is  $\mathcal{O}\left(N^{3.5}\right) $, where  $N$  is the number of variables.

Is this opinion correct? If it is not correct, what is the time complexity for solving this feasibility problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the problem listed above is a linear programming. But I also want to discuss this in a more general form, i.e. "the time complexity for solving a convex feasibility problem".

Comment: Yeah, I think your edit is better. In this question, it's better focus on the linear programming.

Comment: You may want to take a look at [this](https://mathoverflow.net/q/92939/91764)

Comment: An instance of the linear programming problem is called a linear program

Comment: Got it, my bad. Thanks, I will change the "programming" to program

Answer (score 1):

In general, linear programming (LP) can be cast as a linear feasibility (LF) problem by encoding primal/dual feasibility of the polyhedra and strong duality. So there is a polynomial (trivial) [reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial-time_reduction) from LP to LF, which shows that LP is no harder than LF. On the other hand, LF is no harder than LP since we can set the objective to 0 in LP to recover LF (another trivial reduction).

Unless you know something more about your problem, it appears (to me) to be the same complexity as LP.