# Arithmetic cost of determining whether a polyhedron is empty?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, polyhedra

Given a polyhedron of the form $P=\lbrace x \in \mathbb{R}^n:x \geq 0, Ax=b \rbrace$, what is the arithmetic cost in order to determine whether the polyhedron is empty or not.

I know, that one can use Farkas to determine whether a system of linear inequalities has a solution or not, but I don't see, how this plays into the arithmetic cost.

Another idea I had is to use the simplex method an search for a feasible starting tableau. But this seems like quite a complicated approach.

Is there a more efficient one?

Comment: See: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4719478/334300. You can use use interior point methods for a polynomial complexity, but basically your questions is the same as asking to solve an LP (in general, unless you more about your system)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. So if I understand correctly, the complexity is $O(n^{3.5})$?

Comment: Yes (https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/5922/complexity-order-of-the-interior-point-method) though in practice it often seems to be better

Comment: Great Thank you!